# Rails model includes has_many through with order not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'd like to be able to use an order statement with `includes`

My model:

```
DoctorProfile
  has_many :doctor_specialties
  has_many :specialties, -> { order 'doctor_specialties.ordinal' }, through: :doctor_specialties
```

When I try to query `DoctorProfile.includes(:specialties).all` I receive the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "doctor_specialties"
LINE 1: ...WHERE "specialties"."id" IN (91, 69, 72) ORDER BY doctor_spe...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "specialties".* FROM "specialties" WHERE "specialties"."id" IN (91, 69, 72) ORDER BY doctor_specialties.ordinal
```

However, when I remove the order clause I'm able to use the above query.

How can I use include while maintaining the order?

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you join the `doctor_specialities` table, like this:

```
has_many :specialties, -> { joins(:doctor_specialities).order('doctor_specialties.ordinal') }, through: :doctor_specialties
```

That would make sense were this a regular query / scope, so I think it should work here.

Let me know how you get on.

Comment: @user2954587 - did this help? Curious to know if it works.